# gulp: how to update the browser without refresh (for css changes only)

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've setup gulp such that the browser reloads when I make changes. However, for css changes I want the browser to update without refresh, but I'm not sure how to do this. For my current setup I've used [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gulp-as-a-development-web-server--cms-20903) tutorial:

```
var debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    connect.server({
        livereload: true,
        root: ['demo/']
    });
});

gulp.task('livereload', function () {
    gulp.src(['index.html', 'resources/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(watch(['resources/**/*.html', 'index.html']))
        //.pipe(debug({verbose: true}))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('resources/**/*.scss', ['css']);
});
```

In my css task I also call

```
.pipe(livereload());
```

Any suggestions what I need to modify so css updates happen without a refresh ?

UPDATE: Here is my css task (a bit simplified):

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    ...
    return gulp.src('demo.scss')
        .pipe($.sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./target/')
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Comment: Does having `livereload` on the server cause the whole thing to refresh? I haven't used it that way.

Comment: Without a refresh of livereload?

Comment: I have indeed the `livereload` chrome extension. If I disable it, nothing happens!

Comment: Can you add your `css` setup?

Comment: THAT is _simplified_? I'd recommend you test that a _basic_ setup of writing a CSS file to the output and updating the stylesheet in the browser. Ain't nobody got time for that mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `livereload.changed(files)` when change happens. To do that see [gulp-watch doc](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#starting-tasks-on-events).

```
watch('**/*.js', function (files) {
  livereload.changed(files)
});
```

Comment: I actually need to do a refresh too if specific files change. Any suggestions how to force a refresh instead ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri this will reload the page, what do you think this does?

Comment: No it doesn't. It only updates the css. Things like dom structure, javascript instances are not refreshed.

Comment: Oh, I don't know maybe try `livereload()`. why would you need a full refresh anyway, it wouldn't make a difference. @JeanlucaScaljeri

Comment: `livereload()` did the trick!! Thanks a lot! CSS changes can be applied without refresh, however for html or javascript changes you have to refresh. However, I have a situation in which I have to refresh if a specific css file changes :(

Answer (score 1):

you might need a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) for gulp-livereload

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with you, i solved it.

I found it's uncontrolled to use embedded [livereload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload) support in gulp-connect.

So, i tried to make livereload work independently.

Just setup your gulp-connect config without livereload and call livereload.listen with specified host option(at most time it should be 'localhost'). Like

```js
livereload.listen({ host: 'localhost' });
```

And then watch files you want to detect. Like

```js
var changedFile = null;

gulp.task("livereload", function(cb){
    return gulp.src(changedFile)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.watch(['*.css']).on('change', function(file) {
  changedFile = file.path;
  // run specific task according to the given file's extension
  // gulp.start(['livereload']);
});
```